# virtual hosting problems with proftpd

Tags: linux, proftpd

I need a FTP server on linux that supports **name-based Virtual Hosting**.

Based on **proftpd** documents, this package support **name-base** and **ip-base** virtual hosting.
In real I want define two virtual server on a single ip address. Then all user login to the ftp server based on domain name to special directory.

For example we have two site with names **x.y** and **h.n**, and we have ftp user.

My config files are in the following lines:

***/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf***

```
.....
include /etc/proftpd/conf.d/h.conf
include /etc/proftpd/conf.d/x.conf
```

***/etc/proftpd/conf.d/x.conf***

```
<VirtualHost x.y>
MaxLoginAttempts        3
RequireValidShell       no
DefaultRoot             /home/x/
</VirtualHost>
```

***/etc/proftpd/conf.d/h.conf***

```
<VirtualHost h.y>
MaxLoginAttempts        3
RequireValidShell       no
DefaultRoot             /home/h/
</VirtualHost>
```

With these settings when I login yo x.y or h.n, I login to the same of directory that point to the /home/h/.
And if I replace two include lines in **proftpd.conf** with each other that first include **x.conf** then **h.conf**, after login with x.y or h.n the /home/x/ was opened for me.

Comment: You also need a client that supports RFC 7151 and which sends the HOST command for VirtualHosting to work correctly...